# Abstract Algebra - Rings and Units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity. Let $u \in R$ has at least one right inverse. Show that if $u$ has exactly one right inverse, then $u$ is a unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $u$ is not a unit. Then if $v$ is a right inverse of $u$ (this exists by hypothesis), we have $uv=1$ but $vu\neq 1$ (otherwise $v$ would be an inverse of $u$).

Then $u(vu-1)=(uv)u-u=0$, and $u(v+vu-1)=uv+u(vu-1)=uv=1$. So $v'=v+vu-1$ is a right inverse of $u$, and $v'\neq v$ since $vu\neq 1$.